# Adress is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to add some members to a basic linked list (And I'm always adding to the end of the list ).

The List code:

```
void createList(char * name, Test * node) {
    static int flag = 0;

    if(flag == 0 ){
        node->name = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;
        flag = 1;
    }

    Test * newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Test));

    newNode->name = name;

    while(node->next != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
    }

    node->next = newNode;

    free(newNode);

}
```

Where here I'm using a static variable to keep track of whether or not it's the first function call (i.e the list is empty).

The function works fine on it's own, however when i call it to test it (Add some values to the list) as such:

```
int main(void) {
    Test * node;

    node = malloc(sizeof(Test));

    createList("TestName",node);

    printf("First Node in The List is %s\n",node->name); //segfaults

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to segfault and give me the error in the title. 
My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct Test Test;
typedef struct Test {
    char * name;
    Test * next;
} Test;
```

I don't have a header node (I can't change that) so I'm using a static variable as such. I don't think it's a memory issue but possibly the fact that I'm setting the next pointer to a new node, but the original first node is never set? I.e it's always NULL causing the seg fault. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: (NO OFFENSE PLEASE) Your `createList` functions is absurd. Can you explain what it does? In comment for example.

Comment: Well the static flag sets the structs values to NULL on the first Call (To intialize the values to NULL). Then I create a new Node, malloc it, and set it's name to the one given by the caller. I Got through the list till the node->next is not NULL (I.e in this case it exists right away). Then I set the next pointer of the node to the new node. I'm not too familiar with linked lists, so please correct my code if at all possible.

Comment: NO!!! Find a good book where they explain linked lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `createList` you're freeing `newNode` right after you add it to the list, so the data becomes invalid.  You only `free` when you're cleaning up the list.

Also, the first node in the list will always have `name` equal to `NULL`.  So in the `printf` in main you're trying to dereference a NULL pointer, which causes the segfault.

A better thing to is to not create a new node on the first call, since you already have one empty node:

```
void createList(char * name, Test * node) {
    static int flag = 0;

    if(flag == 0 ){
        node->name = strdup(name);
        node->next = NULL;
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        Test * newNode;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(Test));
        newNode->name = strdup(name);

        while(node->next != NULL) {
            node = node->next;
        }

        node->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes it work, thanks! I guess I wasn't too far from getting it to work. Although (Correct me If Im wrong) strdup also malloces the value, so I'll later have to free it?

Comment: Yes, `strdup` allocates space for the string, so you'll have to `free` it later.  You want that however, since it makes the strings in the list independent of their sources.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `node->next = newNode` you only copy the *pointer*, meaning you now have two pointers to the same memory. When you then free that memory you have two pointers pointing to unallocated memory.

Trying to dereference any of those pointers will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The solution is of course to not call `free` on the newly allocated memory.

---

Ah, the above is actually not the cause of your crash, the problem is that you dereference a null pointer. In the `createList` function you do

```
node->name = NULL;
```

then in the `main` function you try to use this null pointer.

In the `main` function, `node` is a dummy node, whose `next` pointer will point to the actual first node.

Now I also see another problem: You don't initialize `newNode->next`, so if you try to dereference `node->next->next` you will again have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Removing the call to free retains the segfault problem. Removing the printf line removes the problem, so somethings wrong with accessing the node->name member.

Comment: @TEDED Ah yes, I see it now, you are doing a null pointer access.

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious problem here:

```
node->next = newNode;

free(newNode);
```

You set a pointer to the new node, and then you delete it. Now the pointer will point nowhere.

You cannot free the memory until you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Hmm, even removing the free still seems to segfault.

Comment: Yes, `node->name` is NULL as the pointer to the name is stored in the `newNode`, not in `node`.